# Adding a custom field to a custom entity?

Tags: java, liferay

I'm making a module application where I hope to add a geolocation field to the add entry form. I figured out you can create a custom field which allows you to add a geolocation. But now in the resources list I don't see my custom entities.
I was hoping to find out if that is a possible approach to my problem?

I'm working with liferay 7.3 and coding in java 1.8

Comment: While you can have custom fields on custom entities, this is a rare request. After all, you're in control of your custom entities, and could easily extend them to have the field that you'd like to add this way as a native field instead of a custom one (the API calls them Expando - and if the UI doesn't show them, you can also create them through the API).

Comment: @OlafKock How can I add a geolocation as a native field? I'm new to liferay, maybe you could give me an example?

Comment: I've missed that detail - sorry, can't tell you from the top of my head.

Comment: @OlafKock That's understandable. Perhaps you could point me in the right direction? So I can learn about native fields and how to create them.

Comment: Typically the DTD (as referenced from service.xml) is a good point to start, but I couldn't find anything geo-related there... (Yes, DTD, don't worry, it's mostly documentation and _really_ worth to read)

Comment: https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017893112-Geolocating-Assets